# Fishshell при загрузке пишет про ошибки

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, shell, fish-shell, pyenv

```
source: Error encountered while sourcing file “/tmp/.psub.dvXjhjLG1W”:
source: No such file or directory
source: Error encountered while sourcing file “/tmp/.psub.4WHqZQaNnB”:
source: No such file or directory
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
```

Как обычно, обновился на убунте и здесь появились эти ошибки, не могу понять, как их убрать, гугление не помогло.
pyenv, насколько понимаю, то это проблема с ним какая-то, но он работает у меня хорошо, как и раньше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это баг в версии 3.1.0, планируется исправление в следующем релизе
источник - https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6613